# Ajax: sending file information without actual file

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I'm writing a web application replacing a c++ program. The goal of the application is to add or take pictures from the browser and then uploading it to a server.

The uploading of a file has two primary steps, checking if file already exists on the server and if not, uploading the file.

I'm wondering how I can make the first primary step in Ajax (sending a file (PHP script is using $_FILES which I can't change) without the actual file content).

The c++ code looks like this:

```
*dataBuffer_ += QByteArray("--") + QByteArray(MULTIPART_BOUNDARY) + QByteArray("\r\n");
*dataBuffer_ += QByteArray("content-disposition: form-data; name=\"expected_size\"\r\n\r\n");
*dataBuffer_ += fileSize.toAscii() + QByteArray("\r\n");

//original size
//Original size of the file before compression and encoding
*dataBuffer_ += QByteArray("--") + QByteArray(MULTIPART_BOUNDARY) + QByteArray("\r\n");
*dataBuffer_ += QByteArray("content-disposition: form-data; name=\"original_size\"\r\n\r\n");
*dataBuffer_ += QString::number(file.size()).toAscii() + QByteArray("\r\n");

//tell upload.php that we have a file to upload
*dataBuffer_ += QByteArray("--") + QByteArray(MULTIPART_BOUNDARY) + QByteArray("\r\n");
*dataBuffer_ += QByteArray("content-disposition: form-data; name=\"mode\"\r\n\r\n");
*dataBuffer_ += QByteArray("check_file\r\n");

//the binary
*dataBuffer_ += QByteArray("--") + QByteArray(MULTIPART_BOUNDARY) + QByteArray("\r\n");
*dataBuffer_ += QByteArray("content-disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"") + file.fileName().toAscii() + QByteArray("\"\r\n");
*dataBuffer_ += QByteArray("content-type: application/zip\r\n\r\n");
*dataBuffer_ += fileBuffer;  
*dataBuffer_ += QByteArray("\r\n");

*dataBuffer_ += QByteArray("--") + QByteArray(MULTIPART_BOUNDARY) + QByteArray("--");
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("expected_size", expected_size);
form.append("original_size", original_size);
form.append("mode", "check_file");
form.append("file", fileInput.files[0]);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', action, true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

This script sends the file information with the actual file, while I only want to send the file information. Anybody knows how I can do this?

Here is the PHP script (which I can't modify):

```
//check if the file was already uploaded to the server (for resuming an upload)
//returns file:exist or file:not_exist
//the post is the same as when transmitting a file, except the data block
if ('check_file' == $_POST['mode'])
 {
     echo "CHECK FILE\n";
  if (!file_exists($_SESSION['localdir']))
  {
    echo "upload:fail\n";
    echo "message:Unable to copy data on server\n";
    exit();
  }

  if (empty($_FILES))
  {
    echo "upload:fail\n";
    echo "message:No files were uploaded to the server\n";
    exit();
  }

    $file = $_FILES['file'];
  $path = $_SESSION['localdir'] . "/" . $file['name'];

    if (file_exists($path))
    {
        echo $file['name'] . "  already exists on the server \n";
        echo "Server file size: " . filesize($path) . "\n";
        echo "Uploaded file size: " . $_POST['original_size'] . " \n";

        if (filesize($path) == $_POST['original_size'])
        {
            echo "file:exist\n";

            //add the file to the global list if it is not already there
            if (!array_search($file['name'], $_SESSION['filenames'], true)) //true=strict
                array_push($_SESSION['filenames'], $file['name']);
        }
        else
            echo "file:not_exist\n";
    }


 }
```

Comment: If you only cares about file name and file size, you can send `files[0].name` and `files[0].size` to server.

Comment: You mean like form.append("file", fileInput.files[0].name)? I didn't know that was possible! Thanks, I will try it out :).

Comment: Beware, `files[0].name` is a **string**, `files[0].size` is an **integer**. You'll have to modify your server-side code to meet this change (since no `$_FILES` available).

Comment: Mm, I feared this would be the case. The problem is they dont want to modify the PHP script :(.

Comment: Your PHP script says that `if(empty($_FILES)) exit();`, so if you can't change PHP side, there's no other way.

Comment: Hi, I fixed the problem, see my answer is you're interested :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it by setting my headers manually (like the c++ code above), my AJAX:

```
var boundary = generateBoundary();

var databuffer = "\r\n";
// set original_size
databuffer += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
databuffer += "content-disposition: form-data; name=\"original_size\"\r\n\r\n";
databuffer += allFiles[index].size + "\r\n";
// set mode
databuffer += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
databuffer += "content-disposition: form-data; name=\"mode\"\r\n\r\n";
databuffer += "check_file\r\n";
// set the file
databuffer += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
databuffer += "content-disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + allFiles[index].name + "\"\r\n";
databuffer += "content-type: application/zip\r\n\r\n";
databuffer += ""; // this is de file content => empty
databuffer += "\r\n";
// end
databuffer += "--" + boundary + "--";
```

This sends the file with the needed information without the actual file content.
I hope this helps other people.